# Python - Remove whitespaces and punctuation without functions

Tags: python, function, space, punctuation

first of all, sorry for my bad english. I'm a beginner programmer and I have some problems with my python program.
I have to make a program that normalizes the whitespaces and the punctuation, for example:

If I put a string called

```
"   hello   how,   are  u?   "
```

The new string has to be...

```
"Hello how are u"
```

But in my code, the result appears like this and I dont know why:

```
 "helloo how,, aree u??"
```

**Note:** I can't use any kind of function like split(), strip(), etc...

Here is my code:

```
from string import punctuation

print("Introduce your string: ")
string = input() + " "
word = ""
new_word = ""
final_string = ""

#This is the main code for the program
for i in range(0, len(string)):
    if (string[i] != " " and (string[i+1] != " " or string[i+1] != punctuation)):
        word += string[i]
    if (string[i] != " " and (string[i+1] == " " or string[i+1] == punctuation)):
        word += string[i] + " "
        new_word += word
        word = ""

#This destroys the last whitespace
for j in range(0,len(new_word)-1):
    final_string += new_word[j]

print(final_string)
```

Thank you all.

**EDIT:**

Now i have this code:

```
letter = False

for element in my_string:
    if (element != " " and element != punctuation):
        letter= True
        word += element


print(word)
```

But now, the problem is that my program doesn't recognize the punctuation so if i put:

```
"Hello   ... how  are u?"
```

It has to be like `"Hellohowareu"`

But it is like:

```
"Hello...howareu?
```

Comment: Can you use `translate`?

Comment: I cant use any kind of function or that, I only can use string.punctuation and the basic code like for, if, while etc...

Comment: And yet you want to strip beginning and ending of the string?

Comment: Yes, I don't want any kind of punctuation or whitespaces at the beginning or end of the all string

Comment: `string[i+1] != [/==] punctuation` compares `string[i+1]` with the *entire* `punctuation` string.  That will never work.  You want `string[i+1] in punctuation` (faster if `punctuation` is a `set`), but beware that `'` is in punctuation, so words like `don't` will be troublesome.

Comment: @Sergio And the spaces in the middle too?

Comment: No whitespaces at the beginning or ending, Yes whitespaces in separation of words

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to write the code for you since this is obviously homework, but I will give you some hints.

I think your approach of checking the next character is a bit error-prone. Rather, I would have a flag that you set when you see a space or punctuation. The next time through the loop, check if the flag is set: if it is, and you still see a space, then ignore it, otherwise, reset the flag to false.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first off, you don't need to loop over a range, strings in python are iterable. For example:

```
my_string = 'How are you?'

for char in my_string:
  #do something each character
```

Secondly, you're using a very spotty methodology for what you want to remove. It seems your method for catching spaces that occur after a character causes a double append of the last character. I would use a different method much more heavily centered on where you are, not what's in front of you.

Comment: Hi @DylanLawrence, thank you for your response but I have a another problem. It doesn't seems to recognize the punctuation and the program appends it to the final word. 
`letter = False;

    for element in my_String:
        if element != " " and element != punctuation:
            letter = True;
            word += element;
    
    print(word);`
   
In theory if i put "Hello how are u?". It has to be "Hellohowareu"
But it is "Hellohowareu?"

Answer (score 0):

Now this looks a lot like homework, so here's my stream processing solution, if you can explain this to your teacher, I doubt they'd mind you didn't really do it yourself

```
def filter(inp):
    for i in inp:
        yield " " if i in " ,.?!;:" else i

def expand(inp):
    for i in inp:
        yield None if i == " " else object(), i

def uniq(inp):
    last = object()
    for key, i in inp:
        if key == last:
            continue
        yield key, i

def compact(inp):
    for key, i in inp:
        yield i

normalised = compact(uniq(expand(filter(input()))))
```